# VS Code does not recognize dotnet build errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I want to create an app using netcore 3.1 The problem is that my vscode seems to warn me nothing about the code (suggesting imports, syntax errors, etc.). For now, I want to create a Hub for my SignalR app, and that's what I see in VSCode and terminal
[image: dotnet terminal build]

[image: VS Code that's not warn me about Hub]

References are added, and I tried clean and reopen vs code

Comment: You can restart VS Code.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) but provide it as text

Comment: Allready tried to resart vs code, even from terminal with code . Does not worked

Comment: @Klaus the problem here is with the IDE not highlighting errors in the code. A screenshot is entirely appropriate here. The console output should better be shown as text though.

Comment: @CodeCaster I agree for the second screenshot, but not for the first.

Comment: @Klaus thanks. My point was that your comment could be considered to be confusing for the OP if you don't explicitly mention that. Also, the actual output isn't that relevant, OP isn't asking us to solve that compiler error.

Comment: @KlausGütter thanks for the advice. I solved it through the post linked to this question, didn't found it on my first search. I should select CRLF and back LF from right bottom corner of vs code

Answer (score 2):

Try disabling and enabling the C# extension and see if Omnisharp is running correctly (which comes along installation on that extension). I've had the same issue before and this solved it for me, let me know if it worked! :)

Comment: Did not worked I disabled/enabled c# extenstions and restart vs code, but no sucess